# How to fix broken Visual Studio uninstallation

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, uninstall, visual-studio

While I was attempting to uninstall Visual Studio 2017, the uninstaller crashed. Because of this, it left parts of the installation folder intact, but not others.

My first attempt to fix this problem was to re-run the installer. Unfortunately, the uninstaller tells me that VS is uninstalled, when it actually is.

My second attempt was to manually delete the installation folder, and all shortcuts to it. While this did work, it left me with a new problem:

When I try to reinstall VS, I can no longer install it to the original folder, and it says that there is already an installation there. This is of course absurd, since the folder doesn't even exist.

Any solutions to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Windows 10 Enterprise (64-bit), Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Did you delete everything under ".../Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio"?

Comment: @wyskoj Yes. `My second attempt was to manually delete the installation folder, and all shortcuts to it. While this did work`

Comment: So you no longer have the problem?

Comment: @Ramhound. No. I can't reinstall it, because it was never properly uninstalled.

Comment: Have you installed it then uninstalled that installation.  Doing that would delete any registry keys that exist

Comment: Does VS appear in programs and features?

Comment: @Ramhound Trying that makes no difference. Even though the uninstaller says that it is successful, the installer still says `Visual Studio Community 2017 is already installed in this folder. You'll need to choose another location`. However, the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community` doesn't exist anyway.

Comment: @wyskoj It does not appear.

Comment: I am not asking you to uninstall your previous installation I am asking you to go ahead and install it to a new location then uninstall that brand new installation.  The installation is being blocked by a simple registry key.

Comment: @Ramhound After doing a full installation and uninstallation to a different folder, the problem persists.

Comment: I did have equal problem) I do - reinstall Windows. Another resolves - didn't effective... Delete VS with "-force" - didn't effective. MSVS did life forever.

Comment: @test123 I ended up just backing up my files and reinstalling windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP notes he self-resolved by performing a clean installation of Windows.